# Removing specific items from a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary inside of a list and I want to remove the square brackets and single quotes inside of them.

```
Current Output:   
[{'label': "['Tennessee'] 22960 Packages", 'value': 'TN'},  
{'label': "['Illinois'] 6277 Packages", 'value': 'IL'},  
{'label': "['California'] 4 Packages", 'value': 'CA'},]

Desired Output:  
[{'label': "Tennessee 22960 Packages", 'value': 'TN'},  
{'label': "Illinois 6277 Packages", 'value': 'IL'},  
{'label': "California 4 Packages", 'value': 'CA'},]
```

Comment: Please edit the code you've written as a [mre] to try solve this problem into your question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with a for loop:

```
m[0]['label'] = m[0]['label'].replace("['", "").replace("']", "")
```

Result:

```
[{'label': 'Tennessee 22960 Packages', 'value': 'TN'}, 
 {'label': "['Illinois'] 6277 Packages", 'value': 'IL'},
 {'label': "['California'] 4 Packages", 'value': 'CA'}]
```

---

With for loop:

```
m = [{'label': "['Tennessee'] 22960 Packages", 'value': 'TN'},  
{'label': "['Illinois'] 6277 Packages", 'value': 'IL'},  
{'label': "['California'] 4 Packages", 'value': 'CA'},]

for i in range(0, 3):
  m[i]['label'] = m[i]['label'].replace("['", "").replace("']", "")
print(m)
```

Comment: getting the error "TypeError: string indices must be integers" my list/dictionary data type is a string for some reason and not a list

Comment: How are you running it as I just did and this was the output: ```[{'label': 'Tennessee 22960 Packages', 'value': 'TN'}, {'label': 'Illinois 6277 Packages', 'value': 'IL'}, {'label': 'California 4 Packages', 'value': 'CA'}]```

Comment: your code works if the object is a list, but mine is a string for some reason.  I generated this list/dictionary from a for loop on a dataframe

Comment: That should have been stated!

Comment: Awesome, i converted it to a list and now it works, thanks!

Comment: Great just come back later and click the check mark on the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def remover(x):
    x['label'] = x['label'].replace("['", "").replace("']", "")
    return x
mylist = [{'label': "['Tennessee'] 22960 Packages", 'value': 'TN'},  
{'label': "['Illinois'] 6277 Packages", 'value': 'IL'},  
{'label': "['California'] 4 Packages", 'value': 'CA'},]
mylist = list(map(remover,mylist))
print (mylist)
```

Comment: getting the error "TypeError: string indices must be integers" my list/dictionary data type is a string for some reason and not a list

Comment: Awesome, i converted it to a list and now it works, thanks!